# Going from Hex To Dec with PIC18?

Tags: c, microcontroller

I have a little issue trying to combine 4 digits together to give me the correct decimal value. First let me start with my code.

```
long firsttwo, secondtwo, combined; 
firsttwo = 0x0C;
secondtwo = 0x6C;
```

The Decimal value of **0C**: 12

The Decimal value of **6C**: 108

But the Decimal value of all **0C6C**: 3180

Now how do I get all the digits into one variable  to be able to convert it to decimal correctely? Because if I just convert `firsttwo` by itself then `secondtwo` by itself I don't get the same final total. Thanks!

Comment: ? `12*256 + 108 = 3180`, looks correct to me. What is the problem?

Comment: I think he is incorrectly expecting `0C6C` to be `12108` or something like that.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: @DanielFischer, so is it suppose to be `combined = firsttwo * 256 + secondtwo;`

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström, I am expecting 3180 as my result.

Comment: Yes, `* 256`, or `* 0x100`, or `<< 8`, whatever your preference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to shift the most significant byte when combining:

```
combined = (firsttwo << 8) | secondtwo;
```

this sets `combined` to 0x0c6c.